# How can I make my Sequence Works with BinaryInteger as upperBound of it in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a function which take a value for upperBound of closedRange for a `for` loop which conform to `BinaryInteger` as I can see in my code, I just made all things right as possible but xCode make this error which I do not know how can I solve it!?

**error:**

```
Protocol 'Sequence' requires that 'V.Stride' conform to 'SignedInteger'
```

**my function:**

```
func test<V: BinaryInteger>(value: V) {
    
    if (value >= 0) {
 
        for index in 0...value {
            
            print(index)
            
        }
        
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Int type instead of BinaryInteger? for, for-loop upper bounds just needed int value.

Comment: @RajaKishan: I know it, but I want with `BinaryInteger`, because `Int` is not `UInt8` or other kind of Integer, I want cover all Integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell swift that the 'value' which is represented by the generic V is comparable stride to be able to use it in a for in loop

```
 func test<V: BinaryInteger>(value: V) where V.Stride:SignedInteger  {
    
    if (value >= 0) {
        for index in 0...value {
            print(index)
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: So why not directly declare `<V: SignedInteger>`?

Comment: BinaryInteger is a more abstract class for all integers and its better to use it with generics